# How to hide an image field from teaser view if video field has data?

Tags: views, 8, hooks

> [image]

```
foreach($view->result as $value){
     if($value->_entity->field_videos->getValue()[0]['target_id']){
      kint($value->_entity->field_blogimage)
    }
```

I am getting following image by kint, I need to set exclude to 0 for image field of this view in views_pre_render hook in drupal 8.

> [image]

Comment: If your view is displaying teasers, wouldn't this be done in node--teaser template or a theme_preprocess_node ? Or I'm failing to understand what you are asking.

Comment: i need to hide for field for teaser view of a specific node, i created a view page and i need to hide image field if video field has data in it

Comment: The view here has no way to alter the displayed data, only for finding the nodes. I see you are using DS, maybe you can alter it in DS teaser display.

Answer (score 1):

```
function mymodule_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, Drupal\Core\Entity\
  EntityInterface $entity, $context) {
  // For nodes, change the view mode when it is teaser.
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  if($current_path=='/dblog'){
    if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node') {
        // kint($entity->getFields()['field_videos']
        //  ->getValue()[0]['target_id']);
        if(!(empty($entity->getFields()['field_videos']
        ->getValue()[0]['target_id']))){
        $view_mode='single';
        }
    }

  }

}
```

well in my case, i solved my problem like this, i created new view mode with needed fields and switched view modes using above hooks.I think this one is a good alternative.Thanks Guys
@OPTASY Canada
@Chriss Happy

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, but I think if you displayed fields and styled them that way, you could:

- Include the image field, above the video field, and exclude it from display.
- In the video fields no results behaviours, you could just add the image field.

Comment: Hey Chris , thanks but using display suite we can make a layout that can be used on all pages, and when display node is display suite , we cannot add any field to view.